# jquery toggleclass another div

Tags: html

The problem is when I click **i** element with ico class, I need to add class **b** to div, which has class **a**. This is what I tried.

My html code is:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="a"></div>
        <div>
            <i class="ico"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="a"></div>
        <div>
            <i class="ico"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="a"></div>
        <div>
            <i class="ico"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.ico').click(function() {
    $('.a').toggleClass('b');
  })

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you want this.

```
$('.ico').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.block').find('.a').toggleClass('b');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear, but this is what I understood.

**fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/jn7z7k2k/2/

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.ico').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().prev().toggleClass('b');
  });
});
```

```css
.ico{
    background:red;
    display:block;
    margin:10px;
}
.block{
    background:green;
    margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
}
.a.b{
    background:blue;
}

.a {
    display:block;
    background:pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="a">anchor</div>
        <div>
            <i class="ico">ico</i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="a">anchor</div>
        <div>
            <i class="ico">ico</i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="a">anchor</div>
        <div>
            <i class="ico">ico</i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: then to what do you want to add ? be a bit specific

Answer (score 0):

I think the event is not properly binded with `ico`

Try Below

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.ico').on('click',function(){
        $('.a').toggleClass('b');
    });

});
```

```css
.a {
    color:red;
}
.b {
   color : green; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="a">TEestete</div>
        <div>
            <i class="ico">Click</i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="a">asdasdas</div>
        <div>
            <i class="ico">Click</i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="a">sadasd</div>
        <div>
            <i class="ico">Click</i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle Here http://jsfiddle.net/vLLtqxw2/1/